# Show records in one row for an ID from multiple columns/rows with null values

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL while retrieving, and processing a data file, I m trying to see records from various columns in one row for an ID so that it ignore null values of other columns and show all values in a single row

Columns col1, col2, col3, col4 with null values for a unique row ID

For this retrieved data table

```
          col1    col2    col3    col4
row1      1       null    null    null
row2      null    2       null    null
row3      null    null    3       null
row4      null    null    null    level1

finalRow  1       2       3       level1
```

```
Select ID, IFNULL(col1, col2, col3, col4 From table t
```

Brings error message. MAX function doesn't work for me as at time MIN values need to be get pickup as well.

Comment: I don't understand. How many columns shall MySQL return?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right, this might be a solution:

```
Select ID, IFNULL(col1, IFNULL(col2, IFNULL(col3, col4))) from ...
```

Comment: Thanks though following error comes "Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'IFNULL'"

Comment: I would like to see the sql-statement that throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example `MAX` will work. In your example there is only one non-null value per column so the maximum value is also the minimum. So, this will get your expected result... which I think is the `finalRow`:

```
select max(col1), max(col2), max(col3), max(col4) from table
```

It would be helpful to provide a better explanation of what you're looking for and also adding more examples.